# Issue Automating Paypal payment submission with Playwright/Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, paypal, automation, browser-automation, playwright

I have an issue that I feel may be fairly unique, but perhaps just me lacking knowledge.

The Scenario: Payment page with a Paypal link. The link opens a new window and asks you to login, select payment and click Submit (Pay). The paypal window closes and the orginal page opens a modal with a progress bar with a redirect and then finally redirects to a payment success page.

I am having trouble with the payment submission. After I click submit, Playwright considers the test done.

What logic do I have to implement so that it waits for the payment submission and triggers the redirect?

Currently I have

```
await page1.click('button[data-testid="submit-button-initial"]');

// Close page
// Click text="Log In"
await page1.click('text="Log In"');

// Click button[data-testid="submit-button-initial"]
await page1.click('button[data-testid="submit-button-initial"]');

// Close page
await page1.close();


// Click text="Payment Processing"
await page.click('text="Payment Processing"');

// Click text=/.*Your payment confirmation and .*/
await page.click("text=/.*Your payment confirmation and .*/");

// Click text=/.*My Applications.*/
await page.click("text=/.*My Applications.*/");
```

When I click on the username and password fields to login, the paypal waiting modal appears. When testing manually, it also performs this for the payment submission. Via automation the payment submission does not have this. What do I need to do so that payment submission is performed correctly so the script can continue?

Comment: Can't you wait for some hint? a selector? a redirect?

Comment: What _hardcoded_ says will definitely solve your problem. If this script is part of a test file it is not clear if you are using it together with **jest** or any matchers like [expect-playwright)](https://github.com/playwright-community/expect-playwright), like that you could ensure it won't pass without matching the requirements of test.